# Wordpress Permalinks issues with custom taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I'm having a lot of issues configuring a required permalinks structure with Wordpress. What I need to achieve sounds simple but it just won't work.

I have created two custom taxonomies, lets call them 'foo_cat' and 'foo_tag'. Inside 'foo_cat', I have 3 categories:

1. Stock
2. Wheels
3. Engines

I need my permalink structure to be as follows: www.domain.com/stock/product_name or www.domain.com/wheels/product_name etc...

I can get this to work by adding filter:

```
function stock_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);  
    if ( is_object( $post ) ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'foo_cat' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%category%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;  
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'stock_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

Then adding:

```
'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => '%category%', 'with_front' => false ),
```

Into my post type and adding `/%category%/%postname%` into my permalink stucture page. This will work, but in return throws back 404 errors for ALL of my pages. If I remove this, my pages work fine, but the products give 404 errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.